# Fixed sidebar with overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, sidebar

I have a problem with an overflow rule on my webpage. So I want to create  2/3, 1/3 layout where sidebar is fixed and links are anchor to Id's on 2/3 side.

I use this code to achieve that:

```
#nav-side {
position: fixed;
width: auto;
height: 70%;
overflow-y: auto;
font-weight: bolder;}
```

So there is plenty of links and on smaller screen there is no way to grasp them all in this container, but on bigger i really don't want to  have this `scroll` bars, how can i achieve that ?

Is there any way to do it without media rules ?

Also, how can I get rid off bottom horizontal scroll bar?

**UPDATE:**

I notice one more problem which puzzle me, sidebar goes on footer when displayed on smaller screen, content and scroll bar. Footer have `z-index: 99999999999;`

Comment: If you only want vertical scrollbars, just use `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;`

Answer (score 1):

add this rule to your #nav-side:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

this way you will get vertical scroll only if there's overflow.

And for the footer add this rule for disabling horizontal scroll:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

**UPDATE**

Since you have `position: fixed`, which means the element is positioned relative to the browser window, you can add `top` or `bottom` rule and define how much you want the sidebar to be from the `top/bottom`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine, now i have one more problem - sidebar when displayed on smaller screen goes on footer - Text and also scroll bar. I already remove z-index from it and give it to footer - How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: did you try to add `top: 0` and `left: 0` something like this positioning? Please explain a little better what happens on small screens

Comment: Here you have [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7eTTfXJcZRaUHBlS2IzeVB0d2M/view?usp=sharing) to gdrive with screenshot.